# POST REST-Web-Service Call for iPhone application

Tags: iphone, web-services, rest, post

Anyone have idea how to pass value from iPhone application to the REST-Webservice using POST method.?

ex:
http://mysite.com/services/updatescore/**uid=1234&score=12658**

I want to send this information using POST request.
- How can I do it.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use ASIHTTPRequest

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"first_name"];
[request setPostValue:@"Copsey" forKey:@"last_name"];
[request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" forKey:@"photo"];
```

See http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use for more info

Comment: The owner of this library is no longer working on it, so may be best to use an alternative library like RESTKit or hand-crack the logic.